# Inserting angle quotes to SQL (ALT 174 and ALT 175 Characters)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need Help in inserting Angle quotes to SQL table column.

Like,

```
  INSERT INTO TABLENAME (TABLEDATA) VALUES ('«Last Name Here»NAME_FIRST«FirstName Here»')
```

Column type is varchar.

I see that ALT 174 and 175 stands for angle quotes but when I tried with that it is not inserting data.

Please help.

Comment: The column type needs to be nvarchar to accept non-ASCI/ANSI characters. Literal nvarchar strings are prefixed with an N, so something like N'String That Has Unicode Characters In It'. It also depends on the Collation of the column as well as the type.

Comment: what sort of error do you see when you try?

Comment: @DForck42 was trying to insert ASCII values of angle quote as I was generating this sql statement through another app; but it was not realizing as angle quotes when inserting. now observed that I can directly use angle quotes and that solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 2):

I had no problem inserting the desired test into a varchar data type column

Please check following script

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use ASCII values in code as I was generating this sql statement dynamically through code, Now realized that using '«' directly also works. Thank you for details.

Comment: @PradeepHegde if this solved your problem then please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (TABLEDATA) VALUES (N'«Last Name Here»NAME_FIRST«FirstName Here»')
```

Comment: care to explain your answer?

Comment: The column type needs to be nvarchar to accept non-ASCI/ANSI characters. Literal nvarchar strings are prefixed with an N, so something like N'String That Has Unicode Characters In It'. It also depends on the Collation of the column as well as the type. – pmbAustin

Comment: but it seems its your server collations by the person who had no problem above

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19333169)

Comment: Consider explaining how your code works *inside the post*. Your answer appears in the Low Quality posts queue, and the lack of an appropriate explanation is likely to be the main reason for this. And @AndrewShmig no, this isn't a link-only answer:)